# Beautifier Algorithm in C/C++

Tags: c, algorithm, indentation

Where can I find an algorithm in C of a beautifier? I need an algorithm that auto-indents the source code of a C code.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you want a tool or an algorithm (code). If a tool, then this is unfortunately off topic for [so] (as per the [help/on-topic]). If an algorithm, then you need to show the code you have thus far and ask a specific question about it.

Comment: Look at the source for Artistic Style. http://astyle.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

The [GNU indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) program is one open source tool that can do this. There are many others.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke vi in ex mode to do this for you.

```
ex test.c -c ':normal gg=GZZ'
```